# Hide Status Bar In SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, swiftui

I refactor my old SwiftUI code and this method no longer works:

```
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Example")
        }
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }

}
```

Works only without NavigationView:

```
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Example")
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to put the `.statusBar` modifier in the parent view, or embed the NavigationView in a `Group {...}`. Although it could be a bug, because the `presentedWindowStyle` and `presentedWindowToolbarStyle` doesn't work for me, too.

Comment: Didn't work even with NavigationView embedded in Group

Comment: Tested in iOS 14.4, the modifier _doesn't_ work in your first example. Tested in iOS 15, the modifier _does_ now work. I won't make an answer yet unless I find a way to make it compatible with iOS 14